# IntelliJ won't open, getting error -10810

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

While I was working on IntelliJ yesterday, my Mac updated Xcode in the background and everything was still working fine. A few hours later I restarted my Mac and ever since my IntellJ won't open. When I try to open it in the terminal, I get the following error:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app with error -10810.
```

I'm using MacOs 10.12.1 and my java version is 1.8.0_111. I've already tried java version 7, but nothing changed. I've also tried the IntelliJ 2016.3 preview version, but with the same result.

Can you help me out?

Comment: Not sure if this it, but it seems like the process table in your MacOS is full. http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/error-10810.html

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and solved it by installing [Apple's version of Java](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US) and then reinstalling the [Sun JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).  I'm guessing that, in your case, Xcode broke the built-in Java from Apple.